# How to handle errors in a nests project: Error vs Exceptions

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm just trying to grasp the general idea.
the code below is just a sketch to illustrate the idea and provide context for the questions.

Things to take into account:

1. My app layer services throw errors: `throw new Error('this is an error')`;
2. I'd like to have an app level interceptor that would ignore http exceptions and intercept and log all errors that we cannot predict.

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorLoggingInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(ErrorLoggingInterceptor.name);

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request: Request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return next.handle().pipe(
      catchError((err: Error | AppError | HttpException) => {
        if (this.isNotHttpException(err)) {
          // could be also a special kind of error thrown in services
          const detail: AppErrorDetail =
            err instanceof AppError ? err.detail : null;
          const message = `Error message: ${err.message}`;
          this.logger.error(
            detail ? `${message}. Detail: ${JSON.stringify(detail)}` : message,
          );
          return throwError(
            () =>
              // mapping error to exception
              new HttpException(
                {
                  message: err?.message,
                  timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
                  route: request.url,
                  method: request.method,
                },
                HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
              ),
          );
        } else {
          this.logger.log('HttpException is ignored');
          return throwError(() => err);
        }
      }),
    );
  }

  isNotHttpException(obj: HttpException | Error): boolean {
    return !(obj instanceof HttpException);
  }
}
```

I have 3 questions in this regard:

1. As mentioned above the services throw errors and as far as I understand, those errors should be mapped to http exceptions. And in Nest it's also done with interceptors. So does it mean I should use a controller level mapping interceptor for for each service error?

For example:

```
export class InvalidNotificationRequestInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    intercept(
        context: ExecutionContext,
        next: CallHandler<any>,
    ): Observable<any> | Promise<Observable<any>> {
        return next.handle().pipe(
            catchError((error) => {
                if (error instanceof InvalidNotificationRequestError) {
                    throw new BadRequestException();
                } else {
                    throw error;
                }
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

2. Will this controller interceptor be always executed before the global one?
3. What status code should be returned to the client in case `isNotHttpException` returns `true`?